# No signing certificate "" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID " " with a private key was found

Tags: ios, gitlab-ci

I created the certificate in apple dev account and run the command in my gitlab runner "xcodebuild -project Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj -scheme Unity-iPhone -archivePath ./dist" but i always get the error mentioned above any solutions ?

Comment: Can you please provide some additional information? Can you provide your sample GitLab CI? Can you provide what sets you've done to set up your xcode account? Can you provide how you're attempting to install your xcode cert?

Comment: Gitlab CI are from the official docs link : https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/03/10/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-projects/ xcode is set to automatically sign can u tell me how to install cert ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.